# Ocultar / Exibir Menu

Tags: android

Tenho o seguinte menu:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_delete"
        android:orderInCategory="100"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_delete_white_32dp"
        android:title="@string/action_faults_delete"
        app:showAsAction="always" />
</menu>
```

Adiciono ele em um `Fragment` da seguinte forma:

```
  @Override
    public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_delete, menu);
    }
```

Nesta tela possuo uma lista de itens selecionáveis!

Gostaria de exibir o menu apenas quando possuo um item selecionado!

Minha dúvida é como ocultar/mostrar este menu?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Não sei se é a melhor forma, mas funciona:

```
private Menu menu;

<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_delete"
        android:orderInCategory="100"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_delete_white_32dp"
        android:title="@string/action_faults_delete"
        android:visible="false" //Adicionado
        app:showAsAction="always" />
</menu>


    @Override
    public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_delete, menu);
        this.menu = menu;  //Adicionado
    }
```

No método o qual você seleciona um item você adiciona o seguinte código.

```
menu.getItem(0).setVisible(true); // Controla a exibição do item do menu True or False
```

Answer (score 1):

rootView = inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_delete, menu);

rootView.setVisibility(View.GONE);